# How can we generate HTML Report of Integration Test in Flutter Automation Testing

Tags: flutter, dart, automation, integration-testing, automation-testing

How can we generate HTML Report of Integration Test in Flutter Automation Testing.

Being an Automation Tester, I've been working on an existing Flutter Automation Project which is running as Integration Test. Like Selenium I also want to generate HTML report of whatever .dart file or testscript being executed.

Hope we get some solid solutions for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Once you could generate the coverage report in lcov.info ( line coverage).
Then you can create the web report as :

- *Generate HTML report*.

*Note: on macOS you need to have lcov installed on your system (`brew install lcov`) to use this:*

- **genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html**

Open the report

- **open coverage/html/index.html**

[image: See example]